# calculate weighted average in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, weighted-average

How to calculate the average weighted by neural networks in PyTorch?

I need to code c
[image]

Comment: The notation here is not well-defined and is not in standard neural network notation `g = h(Wx)` or something like that, so you'll need to provide a bit more context / definitions for the different variables. For instance, are they scalars, vectors, matrices with what size?

Comment: ok, I edited my question

Comment: Eh, not quite. Mathematically, this reads as: sum `u_n`, then divide by the number of elements in `u_n`. (The result is a scalar). Apply `tanh` to that scalar. Then multiply W by that scalar. You need to be more precise about the operation you are trying to accomplish here as it is ambiguous from the limited equation and explanatory text, and the "correct" way to interpret this equation is almost certainly not what you are trying to accomplish.